# Adjust shape dimension in UGS G-code software

Tags: print-quality, diy-3d-printer, print-material, printer-building, arduino-mega-2650

I am quite new to CNC. May I ask how to reduce the length per pixel for the entire triangle? I want the template length, height, and every dimension to be reduced by 10 times, which means the height is 257 mm instead of 2570 mm, length is 275 mm instead of 2750 mm.

Note: The G-code generator software I used is [jscut](http://jscut.org/jscut.html) which is extremely easy to use and it has a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmcmdVhCqu4&t=235s&ab_channel=MakerTutor). May I ask if I should change the overall dimensions in this G-code generator software (jscut) or this UGS runner and how it is done?

[image: Screenshot of UGS software showing a triangle with its measurements]

Comment: CNC related questions that aren't directly related to 3D printing are unsuited for this particular SE. Your question deserves an answer in the appropriate location, but I don't know which SE would be appropriate.

Comment: @fred_dot_u - Maybe [SE.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)? However, this seems to be a general G-code question, which someone might have a answer for. Also, CNC was discussed as (potentially) being [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I think? See the sections **Non-3D Printing related** and **Misc**.

Comment: I've read the linked page and see that it is explicitly allowed, hence my close vote retraction. I wish I was able to answer the question, but the program is tedious to use.